# How to find a 2x2 matrix with integer entries for eigenvalues and eigenvectors using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy

For example, if I had eigenvalues 7 and 20 with eigenvectors (2,3) and (1,3), how would I go about calculating the 2x2 matrix? Can I use python to calculate an array with these integer entries?

Comment: It seems like you are more in search of an [algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54818/construct-matrix-given-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors) rather than a specific code problem? If you have an attempt at the solution please post it, otherwise this question is off topic.

Comment: What are you trying to solve with your sample eigenvalue and eigenvector? Your question is unclear, please update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a math than programming question. To get a matrix with eigenvalues 7 and 20 and eigenvectors [2, 3] and [1, 3] you need to create a matrix `P` which has the eigenvectors as columns and a diagonal matrix `D` with eigenvalues on the main diagonal. Using numpy this would be:

```
import numpy as np

P = np.array([[2, 3], [1, 3]]).T
D = np.diag([7, 20])
```

(this assumes that 7 is the eigenvalue corresponding  [2, 3] and 20 is corresponding to [1, 3]). The matrix you are looking for is obtained by multiplying P*D*P^(-1). With numpy:

```
A = P@D@np.linalg.inv(P)
```

Since numpy is using floating numbers, there is some loss of precision involved in computing the inverse matrix of P. If you want to avoid it and get entries of `A` expressed as fractions you can use sympy instead:

```
from sympy import Matrix, diag

P = Matrix([[2, 3], [1, 3]]).T
D = diag(7, 20)
A = P*D*P**(-1)
```